# How many local method anonymous classes are created?

Tags: java, anonymous-inner-class

Consider this class:

```
public class Activity {

    public ArrayList<testInterface> containerListener = new ArrayList<testInterface>();

    public void metodoDiProva(int num) {
        final int finalNum = num;

        containerListener.add(new testInterface() {

            @Override
            public void metodoDiProva() {
                System.out.println(finalNum);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now just look this method:

```
public void metodoDiProva(int num) {
    final int finalNum = num;

    containerListener.add(new testInterface() {

        @Override
        public void metodoDiProva() {
            System.out.println(finalNum);
        }
    });
}
```

Imagine the `metodoDiProva(int num)` is called 2 times, for example:

```
activityObj.metodoDiProva(10);
activityObj.metodoDiProva(20);
```

so in the arrayList of the listener there are 2 objects:
 
The **first listener object** can use the **finalNum variable**, **the value** of this variable **is 10**.
The **second listener object** can use the **finalNum variable**, **the value** of this variable **is 20**.
The question is:
In the memory there are 2 different InnerClas or only just 1 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is just one inner class; there are two instances of it.  When you compile `Activity`, you will see two .class files: `Activity.class` and `Activity$1.class`, where `Activity$1.class` represents your anonymous inner class.

Comment: Ok, thank you, so who keep the value of  the finalNum variable where for the firstListener is 10, and for the second is 20? the listenerObject? i mean: are the instances of the anonymous class that keep the value of the final variable?

Comment: The inner class gets an implicit member variable for the local variable behind the scenes.  That's also why the local variable must be `final` (or "effectively final" in Java 8), so that the copy's value is guaranteed to be consistent between the inner class and the enclosing class.

Comment: this understand, but if u look the code, for the firstListener the value (inside the anonymous class) of the final variable is 10, for the secondListener (inside the anonymous class) is 20. You said to me that there is only 1 class. So... who keep the value 10 for the firstListener and the value 20 for the secondListener? still the inner anonymous class or the instance of the inner anonymous class?

Comment: @GiovanniFar You can use reflection to see fields of your anonymous class. If you use for instance `for (Field f : containerListener.get(0).getClass().getDeclaredFields()){ System.out.println(f); }` you will see something like `private final int name.of.package.YourClass$1.val$num` which means that anonymous class `$1` has field `val$num` which stores value of argument `num`.

Comment: @GiovanniFar Each instance of the anonymous inner class maintains its own value in the implied instance variable.  The first instance of the anonymous inner class has the value `10`, and the second instance has the value `20`.

Comment: @rgettman So the final variable keeped by the anonymous class are: instance variable (variable of the object of the anonymous class) and NOT static variable of the anonymous class, it is right ?

Comment: Correct, those implicit instance variables in the anonymous inner class are not `static`.